# how to make my labels have a background color?

Tags: python, kivy

I have tried multiple times and it won't work at all. It either shows a black square or a little gray.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.metrics import dp

class WordLabel(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WordLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 5
        self.rows = 6
        self.spacing = 5
        self.pos_hint = {"center_x": .5}
        for i in range(0, 30):
            label = Label(
                pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5},
                text=str(i+1),
                size_hint=(dp(10), dp(10)),
                color=(0, 0, 0, 1),)
            with self.canvas.before:
                Color(0, 0, 0, .25)
                self.rect = Rectangle(
                    pos=self.center,
                    size=(self.width/2., self.height/2.))
            self.add_widget(label)

class WORDOLE5App(App):
    pass

WORDOLE5App().run()
```

I want the labels to be spaced out a little with a light gray background on all of them.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple problems with your code.

First, you are trying to set up positions and sizes in the `__init__()` method. At that point, the positions and sizes of widgets are always the default position and size. So when your code references `self.center`, it will be `(50, 50)`, since the default `pos` is `(0,0)` and the default `size` is `(100,100)`. Simialrly, the `self.width` and `self.height` will both be `100`.

Second, when you set sizes and positions in python like this, the values that are used are those in effect at that time (see above paragraph), and will not be updated later.

Third, you are incorrectly using `size_hint` in your code: `size_hint=(dp(10), dp(10))`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.size_hint_x).

A good way to do what you want is to use the `kv` language. If you set up your sizes, positions, etc in a `kv` file (or string), then those settings will be updated when the default sizes and setting are updated. Here is a modified part of your code that uses the above principles:

```
kv = '''
<MyLabel>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: dp(75), dp(75)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
'''

Builder.load_string(kv)

class MyLabel(Label):
    pass

class WordLabel(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WordLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 5
        self.rows = 6
        self.spacing = 15
        for i in range(0, 30):
            label = MyLabel(text=str(i+1))
            self.add_widget(label)
```

Note that a custom class (`MyLabel`) is defined so that the rules in the `kv` string will only be applied to instances of `MyLabel`, not every `Label` in the `App`.